# in which (year) and in which (city)

Tags: relative-pronouns, archaic-language, demonstrative

Are "year" and "city" optional in the following?

> 1. John returned to London in 2010, in which (year) he married Joanne.
> 2. John returned to London, in which (city) he married Joanne.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: John returned to London in 2010, which is also the year when he married Joanne. John returned to London, where he then married Joanne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first, "in which" should not be used because it isn't clear which noun - 'London' or '2010' - it refers to.

In the second, there is no ambiguity, but it is not a natural way of saying it. In fact, it's not even natural if you do include the word 'city'.

Instead, the first should say "when" or "the year", rather than "in which (year)". The second should use "where" rather than "in which (city)". Alternatively, "the year in which" or "the city in which" could be used.